# Relation between relativistic momentum in center of mass and another particle's rest frames

Tags: special-relativity

Consider a system of 2 particles A and B. I am trying to prove the formula $$|\vec{P}_{CM}|=\frac{m_B}{E_{CM}}|\vec{P}_{A, LAB}|$$ where $|\vec{P}_{CM}|$ and $E_{CM}$ are the momentum of one each one of the particles and the total energy/mass in the center of mass frame, and $|\vec{P}_{A, LAB}|$ is the momentum of particle A in particle B's rest frame. Notice I am using natural units.

I have tried expresing the scalar products of $P^\mu_A$, $P^{\mu}_B$ and the total momentum in the different frames to get the relation using lorentz invariance but I cannot reach the final formula. My main approach was:

$$E^2_{CM}=P_\mu P^\mu = (P_A)_\mu (P_A)^\mu+(P_B)_\mu (P_B)^\mu+2(P_A)_\mu (P_B)^\mu$$

Now the only invariant term that I can think of that gives me the $|\vec{P}_{A, LAB}|$ factor is $(P_A)_\mu (P_A)^\mu$ expanded in the LAB frame. However this gives extra terms that I cannot cancel and does not seem to end up in a proportionality factor. I have tried calculating the other products in both reference frames and getting relations between them but I must be missing something.

Comment: You should show and explain your work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For such calculations it is usually easiest to use the rotational invariance and just do the calculation explicitly in a frame where it is especially simple. For instance
if we choose the $z-$axis along $\vec{p}_{CM}$, then
$$p_A=\begin{pmatrix}E_A\\0\\0\\|\vec{p}_{CM}|\end{pmatrix}, \quad p_B=\begin{pmatrix}E_B\\0\\0\\-|\vec{p}_{CM}|\end{pmatrix}$$
with $E_A+E_B = E_{CM}$.
A lorentz boost in the $z-$direction can be written as
$$\Lambda_z=\begin{pmatrix}\cosh\theta & 0 & 0 & -\sinh\theta \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
-\sinh\theta & 0 & 0 & \cosh\theta\end{pmatrix}$$
since we want this to be a transformation into the rest frame of $B$, we must have
$$
\begin{align}
E'_B &= E_B\cosh\theta + |\vec{p}_{CM}|\sinh\theta 
\overset{!}{=} m_B \\
p'_{B,z} &= -E_B\sinh\theta - |\vec{p}_{CM}|\cosh\theta
\overset{!}{=} 0
\end{align}
$$
from which we get $\cosh\theta=\frac{E_B}{m_B} ~~$ and $~\sinh\theta =-\frac{|\vec{p}_{CM}|}{m_B}$. You can now apply the lorentz transformation to
$p_A$ and should find the above relation for the energies :)

Comment: Thank you, this was really helpful. I guess you might want to correct a typo in the second 4-vector name (P_A instead of P_B) for future readers, though.